# Lightning Container Component: Refused to display '...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I'm following the **official** Salesforce example about Lightning Container Component usage (*Released Winter'18 on API 41.0*): ([RealtyApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm))

I get a message like this on console:
[image]
If I click on the link, I can see this app working in a new tab.

In the example, I see a manifest.json according to [Specifying a CSP Level](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_csp.htm) and no luck, still the same error testing all modes.

Also, I tried with *Basic* Example as well ([GitHub Lightning Container Examples](https://github.com/developerforce/LightningContainerExamples)), but I have the same problem.

I'm using a Trailhead Org to test this example but I run out of ideas to figure out what is going on.

Comment: We just tried to follow the same example on our developer org and personal orgs and we got exactly the same problems, just trying to open the Realty Lighting page which comes out of the box in the Github repository.

And just recently in a brand new org I found it's working. I deployed exactly the same `Realty` source code with `jsforce-deploy` and on a new one. So extrange having it not working on 2 orgs and on the third one not this `Refused to display` error but it working like a charm.

Some light here would be really welcome SF...

Comment: I can confirm the same issue.  I believe the crux of the issue is that the container src is being served from: `<custom-domain>.c.container.lightning.salesforce.com` instead of `<custom-domain>.lightning.salesforce.com`.  Changing the manifest does not affect this issue.

Comment: see the comment here for temporary workaround : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206676/lightning-container-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-option/210190#210190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, we don't know the origin of the problem. We have set a new organization and this component works now.

Comment: We still have the same problem with a new DE org (just signed up right now). Not sure where the difference is.

Comment: @stomita were you able to discover reason for why this was occurring? I am also encountering similar issue in a sandbox, though it works fine in a DE (as this answer suggests)