# Lightning Container refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' (2)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-container

I'm reopening a question for that as it is not resolved (other link [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196520/lightning-container-component-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-se))

I'm still unable to display my Vue JS app in a lightning container. My app is loading from a static resource and I had no luck with getting around this 'X-Frame-Option' set to same origin. It is still trying to load from .c.container.lightning.salesforce.com instead of .lightning.salesforce.com

I've also added a comment to this [repo](https://github.com/developerforce/LightningContainerExamples/issues/7) of developerforce.

If anyone has news from Salesforce or by some magic was able to make it work I would love to know :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling below setting and see if it works. This is not recommended but only temporary workaround while you fix the root cause.

[image]